# Install wasm-32 for stable rust without rustup

Tags: rust, rustup

I have a cloud node where I need a rust toolchain installed. Until now I have installed both stable and nightly with some curl magic and scripts from here:

```
    static-host            = "https://static.rust-lang.org/"
    stable-installer-path  = "dist/rust-1.74.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.tar.gz"
    nightly-installer-path = "dist/rust-nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.tar.gz"
    nightly-wasm-path      = "dist/rust-std-nightly-wasm32-unknown-unknown.tar.gz"
```

```
    curl -ssL "${static-host}/${stable-installer-path}" -o "/etc/rust/$(basename ${stable-installer-path})"
    tar -xzf "/etc/rust/$(basename ${stable-installer-path})" -C /etc/rust

    curl -ssL "${static-host}/${nightly-installer-path}" -o "/etc/rust/$(basename ${nightly-installer-path})"
    tar -xzf "/etc/rust/$(basename ${nightly-installer-path})" -C /etc/rust

    curl -ssL "${static-host}/${nightly-wasm-path}" -o "/etc/rust/$(basename ${nightly-wasm-path})"
    tar -xzf "/etc/rust/$(basename ${nightly-wasm-path})" -C /etc/rust
```

Since our project nolonger uses the nightly tool-chain, I removed all about nightly above,  the stable toolchain still gets installed and runs fine, but it also removes the wasm-target.

On a developer machine it could have been solved by running rustup to install it:

```
rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain stable
```

But I cannot find the stable equivalent to https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/rust-std-nightly-wasm32-unknown-unknown.tar.gz as

https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/rust-std-stable-wasm32-unknown-unknown.tar.gz leads to nowhere.

How shall I modify my static install wasm32 to stable without rustup?

Comment: OT: `/etc` is the wrong place to put a compiler toolchain. According to the [FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard), this kind of addon software should be installed in `/opt`

Comment: Regarding your question, if you run `rustup -v target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain stable` on a developer machine, it should print the URLs of the components it's downloading.

Comment: @Jmb I know, I have inherited this code and the files downloaded in etc was one shortcut I could live with.

Comment: Great I found a link to: https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/2023-12-07/rust-std-1.74.1-wasm32-unknown-unknown.tar.xz

Comment: @Jmb if you write your comment in an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The static urls can be obtained from `rustup` by checking the verbose output.

```
rustup -v target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain stable
```

In my case it downloaded `https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/2023-12-07/rust-std-1.74.1-wasm32-unknown-unknown.tar.xz` a gnuzip compressed file was also available at almost the same destination.
`https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/2023-12-07/rust-std-1.74.1-wasm32-unknown-unknown.tar.gz`

To get the new uri for an upgrade `rustup upgrade` could be ran from a developer machine with the verbose flag, the output is massive but the urls are printed near the top.

```
rustup -v  upgrade
```